# Eliminating gaps between polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, boundaries, gap

I work in ArcMap 10.4 with an Advanced level license. I'm searching for a fast and effective method for eliminating gaps between polygons, so that one polygons follows boundary of the other. In other words - changing shape according to the other polygon (as seen in the example picture - purple polygon's boundary should follow more detailed blue polygon's boundary).

Is there a tool to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of tools that can help with this. Check out this article for more details:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/removing-slivers-or-gaps-between-polygons.htm

More specifically the Align to Shape tool will hopefully solve your problem:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-existing-features/aligning-features-to-a-shape.htm

[image: Align to shape process]

In the future, if you are generating the pink polygon from scratch you could also use the trace tool to follow the blue boundary directly:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-segments-by-tracing-features.htm

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try those out. Unfortunately, I didn't create the polygons, I'm aware of tracing.

Comment: I think there's also an "eliminate" tool that might help. I've used in a slightly different context, but check it out.

Comment: As @Zipper1365 indicated, I wouldn't do this through tracing, I would add on area to the purple polygon that overlaps the blue polygon (a lot of detail isn't necessary).  Then use the clip function while editing, or the erase tool if not, to match the edge to your blue polygons.

Comment: additionally, it the features are in the same feature class, you can use the align edge tool from the topology toolbar to realign each time the edges cross one at time. this can be tedious when the edges take turns overlapping with each other a lot, so i usually reshape one of the feature first (in your case the lower res purple one)  so there is only one  instance of overlap (I make that one feature REALLLLLY overlap) then I just realign that edge.